# How to count values from temp column in PostGIS?

Tags: postgresql, count, postgis

I need to count the total count of calculated values between -10 and 10.
What I have tried to do is:

```
WITH routes as (
SELECT
reg,
heading-lag(heading) over (PARTITION BY reg order by time) AS direction 
FROM my_table 
)
SELECT direction, reg, Count(direction) AS total_count
FROM routes WHERE direction between -10 AND 10
GROUP BY reg, direction;
```

This counts how many of each value between -10 and 10 each route has. But how to count just one values per route in given range?

Comment: Does it solve your problem if you remove the `direction` column from the `GROUP BY` clause?

Comment: if I do so it says  `direction must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`

Comment: I added an answer with a rewritten query. If that does not work or does not suit your case, could you edit the question and add some sample data and what result you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query:

```sql
WITH routes as (
    SELECT
    reg,
    heading-lag(heading) over (PARTITION BY reg order by time) AS direction 
    FROM my_table 
)
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT reg) AS total
FROM routes WHERE direction between -10 AND 10;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this returns total amount for all routes but not the total amount divided by different registration. However, your answer helped me a lot.